# Reading Azure B2C custom attributes with Graph API

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I have created an Azure B2C custom attribute called IsAdmin on the portal, added it to a Sign In / Sign Up user flow, and then using the Graph API, successfully created a new user with IsAdmin = true.  If I then sign in using that new user I can see IsAdmin returned in the token as a claim.  So far so good.

However I can't seem to see that custom attribute when querying via Graph API, nor can I search for it.

```
    var user = await graphClient.Users["{GUID HERE}"]
        .Request()
        .GetResponseAsync();
```

The user is returned, but the custom attribute is not present.

```
    var results = await graphClient.Users
        .Request()
        .Filter("extension_anotherguid_IsAdmin eq true")
        .GetAsync();
```

Returns no results.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: See answer below for how to solve first problem.

The second problem of the filter not working was due to case sensitivity.  Extension names are case sensitive in some places but not others and in my case my user had a an extension name of isAdmin not IsAdmin.  When I recreated the user it then worked correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extensions are not returned by default. You need specify the extension in Select

```
var user = await graphClient.Users["{GUID HERE}"]
        .Request()
        .Select("extension_anotherguid_IsAdmin")
        .GetResponseAsync();
```

The value should be available through `AdditionalData`.

```
var extValue = user.AdditionalData["extension_anotherguid_IsAdmin"];
```

Resources:

[Extensibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-overview)

Comment: Thank you, this solved the first problem and lead me on the way to solving the second!

Answer (score 2):

When storing custom attribute in a B2C tenant, a microsoft's managed app registration is created :

[image]

Take the app id of this app registration, **remove the dashes in the id** and then use it like below :

```py
import requests

# if your app registration b2c extensions app id id is aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee :
b2c-extensions-app-id-without-dashes="aaaaaaaabbbbccccddddeeeeeeeeeeee" 
url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/?$select=extension_{b2c-extensions-app-id-without-dashes}_IsAdmin"
        headers = {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + msgraph_token
        }
r = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
```